# How to check if data exit when I update a JSON file

Tags: python, json, firebase

I'm working with Python and JSON at the same time. My idea is to insert new data from a python file into a JSON file. Exactly, in my python file, I get data from a firebase database, and I insert that that into a JSON file, I'm able to insert new data in the JSON file without deleting any data, my problem is that I don't have any mechanism to avoid duplicate data.

So, first here is the code which is able to get the data from firebase and insert that data into a JSON file:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate(
    "firebasecredentials.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

# read data
# Getting a Document with a known ID

intents = {"intents": []}

with open('intents.json') as json_file:
    olddata = json.load(json_file)
    for ob in olddata['intents']:
        intents['intents'].append(ob)

print("old data:", len(intents['intents']))
results = db.collection('users').document(
    'Peo5kqpi4GORXehD3oQVRXpHGfD2').collection('chats').get()
for index, result in enumerate(results):
    data = result.to_dict()
    intents["intents"].append({
        "tag": f"firebaseImportantData{index}",
        "patterns":   [data["messageQuestion2"],data["messageQuestion3"],data["messageQuestion4"],data["messageQuestion5"],data["messageQuestion6"],data["messageQuestion7"]],
        "responses": [data["IAmessageQuestion8"]]
    })
print("new data: ", len(intents['intents']))
with open("intents.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(intents, outfile)
```

here is an example of my json file:

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "tag": "firebaseImportantData0",
            "patterns": [
                "Hi",
                "Hey",
                "Is anyone there?",
                "Hello",
                "Good day",
                "charlot"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Hey :-)",
                "Hello",
                "Hi there",
                "Hiya",
                "How are you going?",
                "Whats up!",
                "Long time no see!"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

that data I already insert from the database, however if I run again the python file, I will get again the same data, with +1 in the tagname, something like this:

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "tag": "firebaseImportantData1",
            "patterns": [
                "Hi",
                "this a new entry"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Hey :-)",
                "Hello",
                "Hi there",
                "Hiya",
                "How are you going?",
                "Whats up!",
                "Long time no see!"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, in the pattern part "hi", is duplicate, so there is my problem, I don't want duplicate pattern items, and that is what I want to avoid.

So, my question is, Does there exist any way to do not duplicate the data in the JSON file, or how I can avoid to insert data that already exists?

Comment: Can you share an example of the current JSON output and what the expected result would be?

Comment: sure, thanks for your anwser, I already update the question

Comment: JSON is not a good choice for dynamic data.  Have you considered using a local SQLite database for this instead?

Comment: I cant use SQL lite because my project work in a server. Also, thisj son file works as a IA data, I mean, Im using this json file for train my IA. But you are right, is pretty hard to work with dynamic data and json